# Declaring a namespace causes hundreds of compiler errors in cpp, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, undeclared-identifier

I am relatively new to cpp and my code is probably atrocious. However, I am currently trying to implement my own namespace into my program since I want to avoid a conflict between my Polygon class and the windows.h Polygon class. However upon watching some tutorials and reading other threads on how to implement namespaces I implemented my own and while I get no errors in visual studio, I get 303 errors upon compiling (I am using the visual studio local windows debugger), I am compiling in Debug mode for windows x64.

[Here's some of the errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8v9C.png)

Here's my source/implementation Source.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime> // Temp
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h> // Temp
#include <windows.h>

#include "Vec2.h"
#include "Log.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "Boundary.h"
#include "Ray.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include "Polygon.h"
#include "Path.h"
#include "Circle.h"


    // Renderer
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Window* window;
    bool isRunning;
    bool fullscreen;
    // Mouse
    int mouseX;
    int mouseY;
    Uint32 mouse;
    // Keyboard
    GameEngine::Vec2 arrowInp;
    // Collision Stack
    std::vector<GameEngine::Boundary> collisionStack;
    // Log
    GameEngine::Log logger;
    // Physics
    GameEngine::Time deltaTime = GameEngine::Time(0.0f);

    void handleEvents();
    void start();
    void update();
    void render();
    void createWindow();
    void destroyWindow();

    // Non Main
    void collision();

    using GameEngine::Particle;
    using GameEngine::Boundary;
    using GameEngine::Path;
    using GameEngine::Circle;
    using GameEngine::Vec2;

    // Drawing Vars
    Particle particle = Particle(300, 359.99f, Vec2(900, 700));
    Boundary boundaries[] = { Boundary(Vec2(800, 0), Vec2(800, 1000)), Boundary(Vec2(300, 300), Vec2(400, 700)), Boundary(Vec2(300, 700), Vec2(800, 800)) };
    GameEngine::Polygon square = GameEngine::Polygon(Vec2(800, 400), 45, Vec2(400, 200), 4);
    GameEngine::Polygon poly1 = GameEngine::Polygon(Vec2(200, 400), Vec2(200, 200), 6);
    GameEngine::Polygon ellipse = GameEngine::Polygon(Vec2(1200, 600), Vec2(200, 400), 64);
    Path path = Path(Vec2(500, 100));
    Circle circle = Circle(100, Vec2(800, 500));

    GameEngine::Polygon player = GameEngine::Polygon(Vec2(700, 400), 0, Vec2(60, 60), 16);
    float moveSpeed = 1000.0f;

    float rotator = 0;

    int main() { // Entry Point
        clock_t m_LastClock = NULL; // Last Counter = 0

        // Start Counter

        start(); // For user
        while (isRunning) {
            clock_t m_CurrentClock;
            m_CurrentClock = clock(); // Get Counter
            deltaTime.SetTime((float)(m_CurrentClock - m_LastClock) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

            handleEvents();
            render();

            m_LastClock = m_CurrentClock;
        }

        destroyWindow();

        return 0;
    }

    // Initialise the window to draw to
    void createWindow() {
        // Set window size and type
        fullscreen = true;
        Uint32 flags = 0;
        flags = SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;
        if (fullscreen) {
            flags = flags | SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED;
        }
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {
            logger.Message("Subsystems Initialised");

            window = SDL_CreateWindow("2D Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 300, 300, flags);
            if (window) {
                logger.Message("Window Created");
                // Minimum window size
                SDL_SetWindowMinimumSize(window, 1000, 1000);
            }
            // Create Renderer for window
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
            if (renderer) {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 121, 121, 121, 255);
                logger.Message("Renderer Created");
                // Set how to blend alphas and colours
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                isRunning = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void destroyWindow() {
        // Frees memory associated with renderer and window
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);  //error here
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    // Handles SDL events
    void handleEvents() {
        // Check for quit
        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);

        // Check we have latest inputs
        SDL_PumpEvents();

        // Reset inputs
        arrowInp.x = 0; arrowInp.y = 0;

        // If we get quit event, stop running and free up memory
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_LEFT: arrowInp.x = -1; break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT: arrowInp.x = 1; break;
            }
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_UP: arrowInp.y = -1; break;
            case SDLK_DOWN: arrowInp.y = 1; break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


    }

    // Render Function
    void render() {
        // Set back ground colour and clear renderer every frame
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        update();

        // Draw to the screen
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }


    // Called when the program starts
    void start() {
        createWindow();

        path.addPoints(std::vector<Vec2> { Vec2(200, 100), Vec2(200, 800), Vec2(350, 800), Vec2(700, 650), Vec2(400, 400), Vec2(200, 100)});
    }

    // Repeats every frame
    void update() {
        printf("%f secs \n", deltaTime.GetSeconds());
        // Get the mouse' current state
        mouse = SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);
        particle.setPos(Vec2((float)mouseX, (float)mouseY));

        // Draw Boundaries
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);

        rotator += 0.003f;
        poly1.setRot(rotator);


        // Player
        Vec2 velocity = arrowInp * moveSpeed;
        player.setPos(player.Pos += velocity * deltaTime.GetSeconds());
        player.Show(renderer);

        float f = deltaTime.GetSeconds();

        square.Show(renderer);
        poly1.Show(renderer);
        ellipse.Show(renderer);
        path.Show(renderer);

        collision();
    }

    void collision() {
        // Clears stack
        collisionStack.clear();

        // Adds colliders to stack
        square.makeCollider(collisionStack);
        poly1.makeCollider(collisionStack);
        ellipse.makeCollider(collisionStack);
        path.makeCollider(collisionStack);
        player.makeCollider(collisionStack);

        // Draw Particles
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 0, 100);
        particle.collide(renderer, collisionStack);
    }
//// TODO
// deltaTime
// gravity
// collision
// code optimisation
```

Here's my Path.h header (as an example of how my headers are laid out):

```
#ifndef PATH_H
#define PATH_H

#include "Boundary.h"
#include "Vec2.h"
#include "SDL.h"

namespace GameEngine {
    class Path
    {
    private:
        // Properties
        Vec2 pos;
        std::vector<Vec2> points;
        std::vector<Boundary> bounds;

    public:
        // Default Constructor
        Path()
            : pos{ 0, 0 }
        {
        }

        // Specific Constructor takes position
        Path(const Vec2 _pos)
            : pos{ _pos }
        {
        }

        // Adds vertices to path
        void addPoint(const Vec2 point) {
            points.push_back(point);
            makeBounds();
        }

        void addPoints(const std::vector<Vec2> pts) {
            for (Vec2 point : pts) {
                points.push_back(point);
                makeBounds();
            }
        }

        // Shows the path
        void Show(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
            for (Boundary& bound : bounds) {
                bound.Show(renderer);
            }
        }

        // Adds the path to the collision stack
        void makeCollider(std::vector<Boundary>& collisionStack) {
            for (Boundary& bound : bounds) {
                collisionStack.push_back(bound);
            }
        }

    private:
        // Generates the Boundaries for the path
        void makeBounds()
        {
            bounds.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {
                Boundary bound(Vec2(points[i].x + pos.x, points[i].y + pos.y), Vec2(points[i + 1].x + pos.x, points[i + 1].y + pos.y));
                bounds.push_back(bound);
            }
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be most helpful here.  I suspect you missed a semicolon somewhere.  Hard to say.

Comment: @Luca Studwell It seems you do not have header guards.

Comment: Often times a single error will cascade to many, many more. Look at the first error you are getting and focus on fixing that one first. Some of the others will go away.

Comment: And conversely sometimes an error will hide other errors. If you fix one and you know you fixed it, do not be intimidated if more errors show up in the aftermath.

Comment: General rule of thumb: make small changes to small amounts of code. If you have to make a big change, back up the code and hack it down to a much smaller representative example. Make the change on the smaller example. Understand and fix the errors, then apply the change to another copy of the complete code.

Comment: A `#ifndef PATH_H` is missing at start of `Path.h`

Comment: Yea, the #ifndef PATH_H is actually there but for some reason it didn't copy over to stack overflow. I undid my changes and am now going though bit by bit as user4581301 suggested, I seem to be making decent progress. Either way, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I fixed the code format problem. You had code on the same line as ```

Comment: @user4581301: We tend to use Git these days, instead of copying entire codebases.